# cat combining not all file formats - but which ones?

Tags: cat, file-format

In GNU⁄Linux, combining files with `cat` works in miraculous ways – at least for me:

`cat part_* > /destination/file.xyz`

with the same file format for BOTH source and target file(s) works like a charm for formats like `.ogg` and `mpg` and of course lain text files. But I get some quite interesting to weird results with other files.

- `.flac` → Everything works fine, except that the combined file is displayed with the length of the initial file and then playing along all the other parts while still displaying the first file's length (just like the "hidden tracks" on CDs back then)
- `.pdf` → exits without an error message and does nothing except displaying the first file (the one just after `cat` in the command) under the name given as destination, thus basically saving a copy under another name.

**Question**: Is there a way other than Trial & Error to find out which file formats can be merged with `cat` and which can't?

I've got that far that a lot depends on certain header formats inside the files – but then I wonder: "I thought every executable file has to start with a header?!".

Answer (score 1):

You ask,

> Is there a way other than Trial & Error to find out which file formats can be merged with cat and which can't?

And in a comment on another question you write,

> Any chance for me to tell what cat might assume as header and what not

This I think is the fundamental issue: `cat` neither knows nor cares about the file format. It takes one or more files and produces a single output stream that is the result of copying the source files consecutively.

It is then the responsibility of the application that handles the resulting file to determine whether the resultant merged file "makes sense".

For example to merge PDF files it's necessary to use something like `pdftk`; a simple concatenation doesn't work. As you've noticed, some types of digital music file can be concatenated, but others can't. In some cases you might find that one player can handle a concatenated file but another cannot; there is no simple rule.

Answer (score 0):

You basically answered your own question; it depends on whether or not the file-format has a header.

As for "executable" ... a shell-script is "executable", the shell knows how to run it due to it's comment in the first line, and if you merge two scripts you may get meaningful results.  But executables of a binary format, e.g. elf won't work too well if you combine them ;)

Comment: Any chance for me to tell what `cat` might assume as header and what not, like a definition of "this is a header and everything else isn't" or so? This would help greatly!

Comment: Not really. You'd have to compile a list of "headerless file formats" in your own environment, and script a solution using your list and e.g. the **file** command to decide what to conCATenate and what not. Unix tools aren't built to cater to all possible corner cases of what a user might like them to do. They do one job, and do that well.